# How to setup wireless radio to network using 2 nics?

Tags: windows-7, networking

I am having problems setting up this network, hopefully someone can help me.

Laptop <-> Wireless Radio <- ... -> Wireless Radio <-> CPU1( NIC1,NIC2) <-> SWITCH <-> CPU2

I have a computer with 2 NICs (CPU1).  One goes to a wireless radio that connects to a wireless laptop, the other NIC goes to network switch.  I can't connect Wireless Radio to switch due to space constraints.  All the machines and radios are on same network addresses.  I tried using Window's Bridge network which did allow Laptop to reach CPU2, but not CPU1.  What is the way to get this to work so all the computers can talk to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right clicking one of the connections and choosing bridge connection worked for me. Afterwards a third connection called "network bridge" showed up in my connections and the other PC works fine (got DHCP address, can ping other device, and access the web). It took me all of 5 minutes...